# A retained property should always be released in dealloc function, is this right?

Tags: ios

I used to do this till once I found the retain count of one of my retained propery is zero before dealloc function. (This situation is normal or abnormal?)

NOTE: It's a RC condition, not ARC.

For example, I got 4 retained properties below, should they always be released in dealloc function?

If not, how could I know when to release, and when not to release? Manually judge the retainCount?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *fullSizeImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *thumbnailImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *checkedImageView;

- (void)dealloc {   

    [checkedImageView release];
    checkedImageView = nil;

    [fileName release];
    fileName = nil;

    [fullSizeImage release];
    fullSizeImage = nil;

    [thumbnailImage release];
    thumbnailImage = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the question is "always?", then Wain is almost right...

a SHORT answer is YES...

because in general, when someone set-up a property, it means he's going to use it as a property, that is he uses its setter method to initialize it.

BUT (LONG answer): NO, NOT ALWAYS:

what if you, somewhere in your code, initialize the private var associated to the property without it's setter method? Keep in mind that a property is not a var, but just a useful way to get methods from Xcode to get and set a var associated to it.

in other words, when you write in .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileName;
```

and in .m:

```
@synthesize fileName;
```

you are declaring a var called fileName and are asking xcode to create 2 (invisible) methods for you:

a setter, used to set a new retained value in fileName:

```
-(void)setFileName:(NSString *)newString{
    if (fileName == newString) {
        return;
    }
    NSString *oldString = fileName;
    fileName = [newString retain];
    [oldString release];
}
```

and a getter, used to get the value of fileName:

```
-(NSString)fileName{
   return fileName
}
```

so, when you somewhere in your code use:

```
self.fileName = @"ciao";
```

you are using the property setter method, exactly as if you'd call it directly (and you can do it, the invisible method setFileName: really exist):

```
[self setFileName:@"ciao"];
```

doing so, as you can see in the setter method, from now on fileName is retained, and so you should release it in dealloc.

BUT, to answer your question:

if you use the dot rule to set a new string in your var, ok, everything is fine,
but you may decide to set it in the standard way, somewhere, maybe just for mistake:

```
    fileName = @"ciao";
    // code
    fileName = @"Hallo";
    // code
    fileName = @"Bye";
```

this way you are not using the property setter method, but you are using the var directly, and so fileName is not retained, and if you try to release it, well you may get a crash...

PS:
Manually judge the retainCount?

no, never do that

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helps me to understand the diference between `self.property1 = XXX` and `property1 = xxx`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they should always be released in `dealloc`. If you get to dealloc and something is already released and not set to `nil` then you did something wrong with your memory management elsewhere in the app.

Technically in `dealloc` you don't need to set to `nil` after releasing but setting to nil after releasing is a generally good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your `dealloc` is unnecessarily calling the getter for each property and then immediately releasing it.  Just assign `nil` to release the properties:

```
- (void)dealloc {   

    self.checkedImageView = nil;
    self.fileName = nil;
    self.fullSizeImage = nil;
    self.thumbnailImage = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Although if you are following the current trend of letting clang auto-generate your backing instance variables, then this is better, as it won't cause KVO side-effects:

```
- (void)dealloc {   

    [_checkedImageView release];
    [_fileName release];
    [_fullSizeImage release];
    [_thumbnailImage release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they should normally all be released. If you have a retain count of zero, that usually means you've made a mistake somewhere in your memory management code.

You ask: *If not, how could I know when to release, and when not to release? Manually judge the retainCount?*

Possibly, but you could also let Xcode help you, using static analysis. Go to `Product -> Analyze`. It will quite often help you find erroneous releases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When to release? Quite obviously, if your object was holding a reference to another object, and your object goes away, then it should stop holding a reference to the other object. Why would you even look at the retain count? Retain count is about other people holding on the same object, but they are none of your business. They should know what they are doing. So *you* release the object. You do your job; everyone else has to do theirs. The easiest way, as others said, is to assign

```
self.someproperty = nil;
```

If your object was the only one holding a reference, that other object will go away. If others held a reference, it won't go away. Just as everyone would expect. The "release" method should be the only one ever caring about what the retain count of an object is.